Hide definition in a prototype of the declaration section
I have a C header file like this:
/*! @file */

/*!
Does something.

@param a The A.
*/
extern void meow_mix(int a) __MEOW;

__MEOW is defined by the build system.
I want to hide it from the Doxygen documentation.
My Doxyfile is:
PROJECT_NAME           = test
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
PREDEFINED             = "__MEOW="
INPUT                  = test.h

Yet I see this:

Is there a way to hide it?

Cross posted at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/discussions/11218, answer:
Please always mention the doxygen version used.
I think you need to set the setting MACRO_EXPANSION = YES

Yep this works. Thanks!
